# How to find string that matches the particular regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with regular expression `/(a)\18/`. I try to figure out what **string** matched to this regexp will **return true**, but all the possibilities I've already tried return false.

```
/(a)\18/.test('a18'); //false
/(a)\18/.test('aa8'); //false
```

`\18` can't be an octal number, it could be reference to 1st capturing group **(a)** followed by **8** as above, or it could be just escaped **1** followed by **8** as above, but both return false. Can someone explain me what does exactly this particular regular expression consist of? It's essential for me to not change the regular expression. It should look like above. Thank you in advance

```js
var a = /(a)\18/.test('a18');
var b = /(a)\18/.test('aa8');

console.log(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to this question:

**\1 matches the character  with index 18 (110 or 116) literally (case sensitive)**

As per regex101.com:

> 1st Capturing Group (a): a matches the character a literally (case
>   sensitive)
>
> \1 matches the character  with index 18 (110 or 116) literally (case sensitive)
>
> 8 matches the character 8 literally (case sensitive)

Code: `console.log(/(a)\18/.test('a�8')); // returns true`

*Note: This will return false because StackOferflow replaces the actual character by �. To recreate this one, do the following:*

1. Go to regex101.com, write \18 on the RegExp bar.
2. On the right, it explains the pattern. Copy the character there: \1 matches the character *[here there's a pipeline-ish]* with index 18 (110 or 116) literally (case sensitive).
3. Replace that character for � on this code.
4. Run the command and get a true on your console :)

**- or - \1 matches exactly \1**

You're escaping 1 which is not really a special character.
Hence, it's just matching the exact text:

- a and capturing it.
- Exactly \1
- Exactly 8

Code: `console.log(/(a)\18/.test('a\18')); // returns true`

Another example: `console.log(/(a)\18/.test('patata\18')); // returns true`

In this latter case, "patat" is ignored, but it's matching the pattern explained before: a\18

Comment: oh thank you, this link helped me a lot, actually `\1` in my regexp is an octal `\001` number which matches &#001; html character. I tried this solution before but apparently I copier this character in some wrong way.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :) regex101 is always a good idea for RegExp, btw.

Comment: @Paweł: Actually, there is only 1 answer: `\1` is parsed as a `\x01` symbol. The `console.log(/(a)\18/.test('a�8'))` returns false. To make `\18` be parsed as a backreference to the first group and `8`, add something non-matching in between, like `/(a)\1(?:)8/`.

Comment: I think the character is being replaced by StackOverflow editor. Do this: 1) Go to regex101.com, write \18 on the RegExp bar. 2) On the right, it explains the pattern. Copy the character there: \1 matches the character [here there's a pipeline-ish] with index 18 (110 or 116) literally (case sensitive). 3) Replace that character for � on my code. 4) Run the command and get a true on your console :) --- Added explanation to original reply.

Comment: @Wiktor I mentioned that I don't want to change this regex, I was just considering how it works :) And it is not parsed into hex `\x01` but it is shortened octal `\001` (but considering this particular sample finally it's the same character as `\x01`). and indeed, I can't copy this character here in the comment :) on regex101.com, when white my regex, it shows this character, then I can copy it and it works in my sample.